# Ctrl/shift scrolling does not work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently setup a dual boot with Linux Mint (my first time using Linux), and I have problems with modifier key + scrolling. For example:

- VSCode: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + scrolling should scroll horizontally if there is overflowing text. This doesn't work at all.
- Figma (design software): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scrolling should zoom in/out. This doesn't work at all.

Some background, I use a Logitech G Pro X Superlight mouse, and I can confirm both of these scenarios and others work as intended on windows. I'm kind of stuck with why, has anyone got any ideas or can help?

Comment: Why do you say they "should" work this way? Is it documented behavior? If not, you don't necessarily expect the same shortcuts to work for an application on different operating systems. Have you looked at the app settings to see if you can configure this behavior?

Comment: Yes, this is in-built into these apps, its a fact, but are keybinds you can't change at all